# How to make the splash screen background transparent in flutter (for both Android and IOS)?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I want to make the splash screen background transparent so that it shows only an icon on the screen when the app starts.

What I have done so far in *launch_background.xml* for Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/index"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

But what I got was a black background like:

The Image

[image]

What I want, something like this:

[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shpHW.png)

How to approach this problem properly? Thank you!

BTW: What about IOS?

Comment: What do you want to show through the transparency?  The phone background?  That isn't how it works.  The app has its own window.  The black background is what is "behind" the app.

Comment: @Paulw11 Hi, what I want is something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/shpHW.png

Comment: You definitely can't do that on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a splash screen transparent. You need to have a color property for the splash screen background, the best way is to define background colors for both the dark and light them

```
//pubspec.yaml

dependencies:
  //Others
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.0

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#f5f5f5"
  image: "lib/assets/image_assets/splash_image_light.png"
  color_dark: "#0F141A"
  image_dark: "lib/assets/image_assets/splash_image_dark.png"
  android_12:
    color: "#f5f5f5"
    image: "lib/assets/image_assets/splash_image_light.png"
    color_dark: "#0F141A"
    image_dark: "lib/assets/image_assets/splash_image_dark.png"
```